# Converting Bing Map’s “ViewChangeEnded” Event to an Observable sequence in WinRT

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, system.reactive

How I can convert Bing Map’s “ViewChangeEnded”  event to Observable sequence in Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Observable.FromEventPattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.linq.observable.fromeventpattern%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method?

Specifically, something like:

```
var o = Observable.FromEventPattern<ViewChangeEndedEventArgs>(map, "ViewChangedEnded");
```

Comment: Can I ask one more doubt ? How can I observe my subscription on dispatcher in WinRT

Comment: var subScription = o.Throttle(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)).DistinctUntilChanged().ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current).Subscribe(x =>